# GLM prediction values

Tags: r

My `glm` formula:

```
fit.full <- glm(y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f, data=df, family=binomial(logit))
```

`glm` output:

```
Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
a -0.0443 0.0182 -2.43 0.01530 *
b1 -0.3247 0.0898 -3.62 0.00030 ***
c2 0.0948 0.0322 2.94 0.00326 **
```

then i decided to apply `glm` to a reduced model for comparing:

```
fit.reduced <- glm(y ~ a + b1 + c2, data=df, family=binomial(logit))
```

but, above code produced an error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b1' not found

I had to write below code:

```
fit.reduced <- glm(y ~ a + b + c, data=df, family=binomial(logit))
```

Is there any solution to enter only: a, b1 and c2? By the way, b and c variables have 3 and 5 values respectively. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have to append b1 and c2 to the df data frame before doing the reduced fit?  How is the glm supposed to know about those data?

Comment: b1 and c2 are values of b and c variables. They are in df already.

Comment: @ Sotos. b and c variables are multi-nomial categorical ones.

Comment: Can we get `dput(head(df,10))` copy and pasted into your question?

Answer (score 0):

The output from your first model does include both "b1" and "c2" as line labels for coefficients, but that does not mean there are columns with those names. It means that those variables are factors with levels that have those names. The "out-of-the-box" settings of `glm` produce "treatment contrasts, so the coefficients of non-base factor levels are displayed with their variables names followed by their factor level. It would ot make sense to try to produce a reduced model with just those levels since there would be nothing to compare them two if you removed all the cases with the base level values.

If you do want to run a model with the same column names but removing particular levels from consideration, then use the `subset` parameter that `glm` supports.

Comment: You need to show how you "used `subset`" as well as saying in detail what "did not work". You also need to show the output of `str(df)` and expand on exactly what you are attempting to demonstrate.